# Editable spreadsheet control in a webpage

Tags: menu, html, spreadsheet, toolbars

I am trying to place an editable spreadsheet control in a webpage without the menus and toolbars.  I saw the postings about this and the last one said to use Google Docs spreadsheet and then choose Publish.  If you use "?widget=true&headers=false" then the menus and toolbars will be removed.

This works great.  The only problem is the data is not editable!  It's a static spreadsheet.  Is there a way to get the google spreadsheet control in a web page without menus and toolbars but make it editable?

Answer (score 0):

I simply put the spreadsheet control inside a div and used the div to cover up the tool bars and scroll bars, etc.  Worked great.

Here is the html:

```
<div id='spreadsheet' style="position:absolute; top: 900px; left: 3px; width: 1058px; height: 350px;overflow: hidden">
<iframe style="position:relative; top: -143px; left: -48px; width: 1140px; height: 650px;" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zt7JNkuqYKGKxRXSTtgjWeUFnCxRjSLB0UKs1oJk6PY/edit#gid=1047354991?widget=true&amp;headers=false" width="600" height="600"></iframe>
</div>
```